# How to implement FadeIn FadeOut effect for HTML5 canvas objects with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, fade

When working with HTML5 canvas, I am trying to implement a Fade-In Fade-Out effect for my little program. So that A Circle can fadeout and turn into multiple smaller circles.

Assume my Circle is an instance of Circle class:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth();
canvas.height = window.innerHeight();

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
class Circle {
  constructor(opt) {
    this.x = opt.x;
    this.y = opt.y;
    this.radius = opt.radius;
  }

  render() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
  }
}
```

Let's say Circle 1 will fadeout and Circle 2 - 5 will fade in.

How can I implement such effect?

Comment: Well any kind of fade or other animation will need an animation loop (using `requestAnimationFrame()` or `setTimeout()`). The first way that comes to mind to fade a shape is to repeatedly redraw it with changes to the [`.globalAlpha` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalAlpha) each time. Or your circle object doesn't have a property for colour - you could add one and update that each frame.

Comment: @nnnnnn Is there any other way? The `.globalAlpha` will change alpha on the context of the canvas so it affect everything in the canvas. What if I just want to fade out one Circle in my Canvas?

Comment: I believe the `globalAlpha` setting only affects things drawn *after* you set it, so that shouldn't be a problem. But otherwise as suggested in the last sentence of my previous comment add a colour property to the Circle objects and in each animation frame adjust that colour to be more faded and then redraw the circle.